# Using 3D manipulator widget set to rotate moves object instead of rotating

Tags: objects, 3d-view

I have set the 3D manipulator widget to "rotate", but when I select the x-axis rotate I grab the object instead:

[image]

Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks for reading :)

Comment: How are you "selecting the x-axis"?

Comment: The way I'm doing in the GIF. I mean that I grab the x-axis rotate handle, but instead of rotating the object like expected, i grab it instead.

Comment: Yes, but what exactly are you doing to grab it?

Comment: I hover the mouse on top of the red curve and press and hold the left mouse button to "hold" onto it.

Comment: Are you sure you're left clicking? I only ask because the only way I can duplicate your problem is by right clicking.

Comment: In my blender setup I select objects with left-click and move the 3D cursor with right-click. If I click with right-click I only move the 3D cursor to that point. If you duplicate my problem by right-clicking, what happens when you left-click? Do you then rotate the object or move the 3D cursor?

Comment: I have the default settings. If I switch to your settings, I can't duplicate your problem at all. The object rotates when I left click and drag with either setting.

Comment: That's how it used to work for me, but now it doesn't.